# LDAP Authentication with Spring Security 3

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I'm trying to secure parts of my Spring 3 MVC web application by authenticating against my organization's LDAP server. I'm new to LDAP so I'm learning as I go. I've been following the documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html) and the example [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/9b423a7726e999b6c80e8c4a769a99dd634f56ce/samples/ldap/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml) but I can't seem to get it right.

Here is my security-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Security Configuration -->
    <s:http>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/page/tosecure/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <s:http-basic />
    </s:http>

    <s:ldap-server root="dc=ldap,dc=sub,dc=myorg,dc=org" url="ldap.sub.myorg.org" port="636" />

    <s:authentication-manager>
        <s:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0},cn=users" />
        <s:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </s:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldaps://ldap.sub.myorg.org:636/dc=ldap,dc=sub,dc=myorg,dc=org" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <list>
                        <value>uid={0},cn=users</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <constructor-arg value="cn=groups" />
                <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And here is the error I am getting (the last few causes listed in the stack trace)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "." (46), after : ""
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 106 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "." (46), after : ""
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 115 more
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.BadLdapGrammarException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "." (46), after : ""
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName.parse(DistinguishedName.java:224)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName.<init>(DistinguishedName.java:174)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.setBase(AbstractContextSource.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.<init>(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.core.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "." (46), after : ""
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImplTokenManager.getNextToken(DnParserImplTokenManager.java:678)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImpl.jj_consume_token(DnParserImpl.java:231)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImpl.SpacedEquals(DnParserImpl.java:114)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImpl.attributeTypeAndValue(DnParserImpl.java:94)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImpl.rdn(DnParserImpl.java:58)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DnParserImpl.dn(DnParserImpl.java:23)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName.parse(DistinguishedName.java:218)
```

It appears that it doesn't like the URL that is listed in the the constructor-arg for the contextSource bean although I'm not sure why.

Also, I have a suspicion that other parts of this configuration are incorrect. For instance, I have the ldap server URL defined in the ldap-server tag and in the contextSource bean. That seems like unneeded duplication but it's how it is done in the examples. Could someone take a good look at the configuration to make sure it is sane?

In addition, in case it's necessary, I'll talk a little about our LDAP server layout since it seems to be a little non-standard. A user's DN is constructed by uid={the_user_name},cn=users,dc=ldap,dc=sub,dc=myorg,dc=org. Group DNs are cn={group_name},cn=groups,dc=ldap,dc=sub,dc=myorg,dc=org and the members of a group are defined by a memberUid attribute. I say this is non-standard because, from what I've read, groups should be defined by an ou instead. But hopefully spring security can handle this setup. Does this configuration properly fetch the roles (groups) a user belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the `ldap-server` element? You shouldn't need it and you haven't configured it with a proper URL (it should probably start with `ldap://` or `ldaps://`).

The example you've linked to uses an embedded server and is illustrating both namespace and bean configurations for the same thing.

The group attribute defaults to `cn`, so that should be correct for your setup. The Javadoc for [`DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.html) gives quite a good description of how it works.

Comment: With your help I simplified by configuration down to this
`<s:http>
  <s:intercept-url pattern="/page/tosecure/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
  <s:http-basic />
</s:http>
 
<s:ldap-server url="ldaps://ldap.sub.myorg.org/dc=ldap,dc=sub,dc=myorg,dc=org" port="636"/>

<s:authentication-manager>
  <s:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0},cn=users" />
</s:authentication-manager>`

Comment: However, I want to be able to restrict access to a particular group. In the intercept-url I changed the access to ROLE_GROUPNAME and added `group-search-filter="memberUid={0}"` to the s:ldap-authentication-provider but I'm always denied access. The docs said that group-search-filter will be substitute the full DN and not just the username like my LDAP server has. How do I configure this to match my LDAP server?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Instead of group-search-filter="memberUid={0}" I should have group-search-filter="memberUid={1}" in the case where the group contains just the username and not the full DN.